# Функция (multi-statement) vs Процедура для возвращения данных

Tags: sql-server, функции, procedure

У меня есть inline функцию, которая прекрасно работала долгое время: её назначение - возвращать 1 строку из 1 поля.
В связи с новыми реалиями проекта, внутренняя логика функции сильно усложняется и оставить её в inline-виде не представляется возможным (при этом, она всё также будет возвращать всего 1 поле).

Функция НЕ используется в джоинах, её результат записывается в переменную, на основании которой рождается дальнейшая бизнес-логика.

Сейчас передо мной встал вопрос, во что превратить мой код: в multi-statement (msf) функцию или в процедуру с выходным параметром.

Насколько мне известно, проблема msf заключается в том, что де факто она возвращает табличную переменную, по которым ms sql server не умеет собирать статистику, что рождает закономерные проблемы в попытках заджониться на эту функцию. А мне, как уже было сказано, такое не грозит.

Подскажите, пожалуйста:

1. правильно ли я понимаю всё проблематику msf или там есть ещё какие-то нюансы в исполнении самих запросов "под капотом" ?
2. что посоветуете выбрать, процедуру с выходным параметром или msf? или есть третий вариант?

p.s. ms sql server

Comment: Тут, пожалуй, стоит прикинуть на перспективу следующее. Скажем, если это будет функция. Может ли захотеться внутри вызвать процедуру, выполнить DML-операцию, использовать #- (а не @-) таблицу? И наоборот. Если это будет процедура. Может ли захотеться, чтобы это была не процедура, а функция (чтобы можно было внедрить её в запрос)?